# In what order does beforeEach and beforeAll execute?

Tags: testing, jestjs

I'm using Jest-Puppeteer to end2end test a Rails application. Before these tests I want to run some seeds and to work DRY I tell the server to go to a certain URL before each test.

```js
// imports

describe("user can", () => {
  // here there are some constants

  let page;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await executeSeed(const1);
    await executeSeed(const2);
    await executeSeed(const3);

    page = await newPrivatePage();
    await login(page);
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await page.goto(baseUrl("/some-route"));
  });

  describe("view some great files", () => {

});
```

I'd expect the seeds to be executed first, since this is beforeAll and if the first test finishes the beforeEach will be done again, but I can't find it in the documentation of jest (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeallfn-timeout)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can read this article https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown.html on Jest document.

```js
beforeAll(() => console.log('1 - beforeAll'));
afterAll(() => console.log('1 - afterAll'));
beforeEach(() => console.log('1 - beforeEach'));
afterEach(() => console.log('1 - afterEach'));

test('', () => console.log('1 - test'));

describe('Scoped / Nested block', () => {
  beforeAll(() => console.log('2 - beforeAll'));
  afterAll(() => console.log('2 - afterAll'));
  beforeEach(() => console.log('2 - beforeEach'));
  afterEach(() => console.log('2 - afterEach'));

  test('', () => console.log('2 - test'));
});

// Execution order
// 1 - beforeAll
// 1 - beforeEach
// 1 - test
// 1 - afterEach
// 2 - beforeAll
// 1 - beforeEach
// 2 - beforeEach
// 2 - test
// 2 - afterEach
// 1 - afterEach
// 2 - afterAll
// 1 - afterAll
```

As you can see, `beforeAll` will be run before all of your test be executed. `beforeEach` will be run before each of you test. So `beforeAll` will be run before `beforeEach`

Comment: Note, that a scoped `beforeAll` in a nested `describe` will run **before** a parent `beforeEach`. So if you depend on something in a parent `beforeEach` in your scoped `beforeAll`, it will not have run yet.

Comment: If you were looking for Jasmine and Google sent you here, change `test` to `it` in both places it's used and you'll get an exceptionally useful but slightly different answer. `1 - beforeAll, 2 - beforeAll, 1 - beforeEach, 2 - beforeEach, 2 - test, 2 - afterEach, 1 - afterEach, 2 - afterAll, 1 - beforeEach, 1 - test, 1 - afterEach,`

Comment: @ruffin can you put this in an answer instead of a comment? I think it's quite relevant